# reading xml form URL with from jsp

Tags: jsp

How i can read a xml file from a url

example: http://eampl.ecom/text.xml

and show exact the whole xml body in jsp page?

I have tried jdom in jsp

```
<%@ page import="org.jdom2.Document" %>
<%@ page import="org.jdom2.Element" %>
<%@ page import="org.jdom2.input.*" %>


 <%

                StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                 // Create a URLConnection object for a URL
                 URL url = new URL( "http://eampl.ecom/text.xml" );
                 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                 HttpURLConnection httpConn;

                 httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
                 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
                 String line;

                 while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                  responseBuilder.append(line + '\n');

                 }
                 out.println(responseBuilder.toString());


                }
                catch(Exception e){
                 out.println(e);
                }





    %>
```

but its only returning value. I need the full xml body with value. Can any one guide me please?

Comment: can you post an example of what it is returning and what it should return?

Comment: I have solved from below example:http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/parsing-xml.shtml

Comment: You shouldn't really be doing this in a JSP file, as it makes the jsp messy and hard to understand. Consider using an MVC framework e.g. SpringMVC and reading the file in an action (controller) and then outputting on the result in the JSP